# Cardinality of Two Sets of Points

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is stated-

Do the following two sets of points have the same cardinality and if so, establish a bijection:

A line segment of length four and half of the circumference of radius one (including both endpoints).

My reasoning is they do have the same cardinality and my bijection is a picture in which I drew a horizontal line and a semicircle under it  (separated by approx. 2cm with the semicircle's open side facing down).  At what would be the center of the circle made by the semi-circle I drew a point P.  I then drew lines vertical from the original horizontal line to point P.  This shows, goes my reasoning, that for every point on the line there is a corresponding point on the semi-circle.

My question is is this drawing enough to show a bijection or do I need to do more?

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: You can simply use the line segment to parameterize the semicircle, as would be done in a vector calculus class. $x = \cos(\pi t/4)$, $y = \sin(\pi t / 4)$.

Answer (score 2):

I think your lines are not vertical, right?  With your construction, there are points on the semi-circle that do not have a corresponding point on the line.  But you are quite close.  You can 1) modify the construction so that every line from P through the semicircle hits the line (and still have every line from the line segment hit the semi-circle.  What does that tell you about the endpoints of each?) Or 2)find another construction that injects the semi-circle into the line, then argue from the Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem.